# How to call a function stored as a variable in python with parameters? -- type error gets thrown

Tags: python

I am trying to store a function as a variable and pass parameters to the function through the variable.  So for example, consider this:

```
def the_funct(*args):
    the_sum = 0
    for arg in args:
        the_sum += arg
    return the_sum
```

If I set the function like this:
    `the_var = the_funct()`

And then try to call it like this:

```
    print('the var: ' + str(the_var(5)))
    print('***********')
```

It throws a type error like this:
`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

If I do this:

```
print('the var: ' + str(the_var))
    print('***********')
```

It evaluates.

So I think I'm missing something fundamental about passing parameters into functions that are stored as variables...any ideas for what it might be?  Other threads I've read suggest the above should work.

Comment: `the_var` is not a function, so why are you calling it?

Comment: `the_var = the_funct()` You asked python to "run"/call the function, and then assigned only the *return* of it. Note the brackets after `the_funct()` . If you want to assign the function, don't call the function, leave the brackets out.

Comment: @Austin: I want to be able to pass the function around like a lambda but without the limitation presented by lambdas.  There may be better ways of doing this than what I'm attempting, so any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If I set the function like this: the_var = the_funct()
```

This way you asked for result of `the_funct`, which is 0 without parameters.

If you want to alias your function, use 
`the_var = the_funct`

Comment: Just what I needed; thanks!  I'll accept it as the answer after SO allows me to

Answer (score 3):

`the_var = the_funct()` executes the definition of `the_funct` and assigns the return value back to `the var`, which is an integer. Hence when you try to call 
`the_var(5)`, the integer is being used as a function, hence the error  `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

```
the_var = the_funct()
print(the_var) #Outputs 0
```

You want to instead do `the_var = the_funct` which assigns the name of function to `the_var`

```
the_var = the_funct
print(the_var) #Outputs <function the_funct at ......>
```

Your output then will be

```
the var: 5
***********
```